# create build zip on Azure DevOps Server like github

Tags: azure, github, build

Currently, I am using Azure DevOps Server for managing my projects.
Before that I used GitHub.

Github has a release feature form where we can download source code of any previous release. As here
[Release list preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BG2R.png)

So,
does anyone know how do I just create a source code zip of the project in azure DevOps
which stores on a server and whenever I need it? I can download zip of that version source code like Github.

Anything similar where I can store full source code as zip of that version.
so in the future whenever I need the source code of the project I can get it any time.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to associate an Azure pipeline in order to  [release artifacts and artifact sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops)

> - A release is a collection of artifacts in your DevOps CI/CD processes.
> - An artifact is a deployable component of your application.
>
> Azure Pipelines can deploy artifacts that are produced by a wide range of artifact sources, and stored in different types of artifact repositories.

That can include the use of [Archive Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops), in order to generate the same kind of "`source code (zip)`" seen with GitHub.
Example ([from here](https://blog.madd0.com/2020/01/30/7-zip-compression-levels-in-azure-devops-archive-files-task/), by [Mauricio Díaz Orlich](https://twitter.com/madd0)), to be adapted to your case:

```yaml
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Compress Files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: '7z'
    sevenZipCompression: 'maximum'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
```